# Eclipse Virgo vs Apache Servicemix

Tags: java, osgi, apache-servicemix, eclipse-virgo

I'm new to OSGi topic, but try to learn something about this technology.

After some resarch, I can't find answer to the question: What is the real difference between Eclipse Virgo and Apache ServiceMix?

What I've done to reveal this mystery myself. I've looked at both and first I thought that Virgo seems to be something like a web server for OSGi while ServiceMix more like a bus. But then I saw that ServiceMix attached jetty and I can even add a web console feature to manage ServiceMix from the browser, so I got totally confused. Now I don't know, mayby Virgo and ServiceMix are the same kind of software, but with diffrent bundles and producer (similar to e.g. jetty and tomcat)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Virgo and Apache Karaf are OSGi Runtime Containers both containing also the feature of deploying web applications which are deployed to an underlying web-container. Apache ServiceMix does provide an ESB on top of Karaf so ServiceMix actually does more than Virgo.